# Cloned a flutter project from Github recieving this dart/firebase error

Tags: android, flutter, mobile

details further>
I'm getting these errors when I open the main.dart file, I prev tried running on VS code but now the same error persists on AS, after checking a few opened issues on github and stackoverflow I couldnt resolve it so here I am hoping to get information on this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9hMVb.png)
here's my pubspec.yaml file:

...
environment:
sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"
...

The error I'm getting is:

The current Dart SDK version is 2.13.0-77.0.dev.

Because fyp_prototype depends on google_maps_flutter >=2.0.10 which requires SDK version >=2.14.0 <4.0.0, version solving failed.
pub finished with exit code 1

I've tried running flutter upgrade but the error is still there [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DUcpq.png)

Comment: Please recheck your question. It seems like you forgot to add the error you mentioned.

Comment: plz check my images attached

Comment: Please format your question properly, at least tag that error as a block quote. And that image wasn't really necessary as you already posted what the image contains